# Не работает HTTPS прокси для requests запросов

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, requests, proxy

У меня есть несколько валидных прокси, но проблема в том, что запросы через HTTP проходят, а через HTTPS нет.

Ошибка:

```
ValueError: check_hostname requires server_hostname
```

Код:

```
import requests
import urllib3

proxyDict = {
    "http":"http://8.210.155.56:80",
    "https":"https://189.201.134.13:8080"
}
    
r = requests.get('https://2ip.ru',proxies=proxyDict)
    
print(r.text)
```

Что делать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело явно в ваших прокси, один из которых не является https, а второй - совсем нерабочий:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Используйте рабочие адреса:

```
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36'}
proxy_dict = {
    "http":"http://87.237.234.187:3128",
    "https":"https://87.237.234.187:3128"
}

r = requests.get('https://2ip.ru', headers=headers, proxies=proxy_dict, verify=False)
print(r.text)
```

Отдает нормальный ответ...

Comment: Но вы же не используете прокси которые занесли в словарь, при передаче та же ошибка

Comment: ValueError: check_hostname requires server_hostname

Comment: @videx таки да: без proxies приходит ответ, а с ними (менял несколько, даже платный анонимный) - `ValueError: check_hostname requires server_hostname`... 2ip - крепкий орешек )) посмотрю еще варианты